# how to play video file from documents folder in ipad application

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, document

I am recording video and saving it to documents folder and i want to play it again later using the video path but it is not playing i am using following code to get path of the file in documents folder and then play it

```
          NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];



      NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy||HH:mm:SS"];
      NSDate *now = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
      NSDate* theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
      NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default Album"];
     if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
     NSString *videopath= [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mov",documentsDirectory,theDate]] autorelease];
     NSLog(@"Vide Path %@",videopath);
     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:videopath ofType:@"mov" inDirectory:nil];
     NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
     player= [[ MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
     [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
```

can you please help me out thanks.

Comment: from your code you didn't saved your video.

Comment: @Vedchi i am recording video from ipad and then i press use button than it saves

Comment: @Vedchi can you please help me out to solve this

Comment: then use the path you used to save video in document directory,not the above constructed path. Using NSDateFormatter & NSDate, you are creating a new path that actually doesn't exists in documents directory.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
NSString *videopath = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mov",documentsDirectory,theDate]] autorelease];
```

you can try without `.mov` extension. Because you will tell extension in this line.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:videopath ofType:@"mov" inDirectory:nil];
```

**Note:** In this line

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
```

If player has retained property, it will cause memory leak..

Comment: it is giving error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: video path NSLOg is Vide Path /Users/malikwahajahmed/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/18A4A444-9F5D-4910-91EE-237918F46CD0/Documents/17-04-2013||14:10:44.mov

Comment: Instead of this `stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mov"`, use this `stringWithFormat:@"%@\'/%@.mov"`. And I cann't see edited code, did you revert with your old code?

Comment: comment this line `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:videopath ofType:@"mov" inDirectory:nil];` and try one more time.. and replace `path` by `videopath` in `[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]`

Comment: Last try. `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy||HH:mm:SS"];`, change formatter to `@"dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:SS"`

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to add the mediaplayer framework in your project and then add import statement

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

and then follow the below code

```
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aVideoUrl]];



        // Register this class as an observer instead
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:playerVC.moviePlayer];


        // Set the modal transition style of your choice
        //playerVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerVC];
        [playerVC.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        [playerVC.moviePlayer play];
        [playerVC.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];



- (void)movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    // Obtain the reason why the movie playback finished
    NSNumber *finishReason = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];

    // Dismiss the view controller ONLY when the reason is not "playback ended"
    if ([finishReason intValue] != MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded)
    {
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [aNotification object];

        // Remove this class from the observers
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                      object:moviePlayer];

        // Dismiss the view controller
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```